# push up weight distribution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statics

I'm about 84 Kg, in push up position (hands on the scales) the scales show about 54 Kg. Can anyone explain briefly the physics of the weight distribution? (I did high school physics decades ago - can't remember much of it now.) Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the physics of the weight distribution"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are wondering why the weight isn't evenly split between your hands and feet. The answer has to do with where your center of mass is.

For example, consider a wheelbarrow carrying some load. Ideally, you would want the load to be directly over the wheel. Then almost all the weight would be carried by the wheel and none by the handles. However, the closer the load is placed to the handles, the more force you have to lift on the handles with.

The key physics concept here is torque balance. With the center of mass close to the wheel, the wheel force has a very short lever arm with respect to the center of mass, while the handle force has a large lever arm. Since bigger lever arm means bigger torque, the handle needs only a small force to counter the torque from the wheel. On the other hand, when the load is closer to the handle, the lever arms or more equal, so the forces need to be more equal.

Your case is similar to the wheelbarrow. Your center of mass is closer to your hands, so there needs to be a larger force there in order for torque to be balanced.